# Evitar notación científica en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda con respecto si exista alguna función que evite que al momento de escribir un numero demasiado grande en javascript me lo imprima automáticamente a notación cientifica. Ejemplo:

```
var noEnExponencial = 20000000000000000000000000000000000;

console.log(noEnExponencial) /* me imprime esto 2e+34 pero yo quiero que me imprima 20000000000000000000000000000000000*/
```

Esto es un ejemplo sencillo, en realidad el gran valor los obtengo de operaciones que trabajan con inputs, pero el punto es que no se porque me lo pinta en notación científica, yo requiero que me aparezcan los números en formato real.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var noEnExponencial = 20000000000000000000000000000000000;

console.log(noEnExponencial) //2e+34
console.log( noEnExponencial.toLocaleString() ); //20.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000
```

Comment: Gracias, lo regresa en string no existe manera de que lo regrese a númerico? o algún consejo a la hora de llevar a cabo una comparacion con otra cantidad por ejemplo: 
noEnExponencia <= 30000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @JLGallardoV por lo que vi es mas fácil y limpio seguir usando la variable numérica noEnExponencial para comparacion y operaciones. Para imprimir el dato como necesitas utilizar el cast .toLocaleString() .

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias :)